# Why does skimage.imread() not return RGB values for my bmp?

Tags: python, rgb, bmp

I'm trying to slice chunks from a bmp image to use for image correlation, however, when I take a single plane from the array returned by skimage.imread(), instead of getting the red plane or the green plane, I get weird colors, as if the original data is in hsl.

I've tried converting the image to RGB using PIL but the colors just get worse...

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

I'm sure my question needs more info, so let me know what I need to add, please and thanks!

Edit:

```
from skimage import data
full=data.imread("Cam_1.bmp")
green_template = full[144:194,297:347,1]    #Both give me a sort of reddish square
red_template = full[145:195,252:302,0]
```

FWIW if skimage.match_template would take color images, I wouldn't have this problem... Is there a correlation library that does color?

Here's the image I'm working with:[image]

Here's what results when I display the small crops made with the code above:[image]

Also using `full = numpy.array(image)` after opening with PIL yields the same results.

Comment: Can you provide the BMP?

Comment: Here's an example that works fine for me, maybe you can provide your example that does NOT work?

`import skimage.io 

skimage.io.imread('http://vaxa.wvnet.edu/vmswww/images/test4.bmp')`

(Comment editor won't let me have multi-line code)

Comment: Can you show that you're able to split into the different planes? I tried that particular module, and it still doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out (with the help of a friend).

I don't totally understand why my pictures were displaying so weirdly, but I do know why they weren't displaying as red and green planes.

```
green_template = full[144:194,297:347,1]
red_template = full[145:195,252:302,0]
```

These were taking one slice from the final subarray, which would be the g and r values, respectively. What I should have done, if I wanted to display them properly, is create a new image with the green_template and red_template as the respective g and r values, and zeros in the other places, e.g. make it back into an array with shape (width,height,3).
For example:

```
import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open('Cam_1.bmp')
#im.show()
r,g,b = im.split()

y = Image.fromarray(np.zeros(im.size[0]*im.size[1]).reshape(im.size[1],im.size[0]).astype('float')).convert("L")

red = Image.merge("RGB",(r,y,y))

green = Image.merge("RGB",(y,g,y))
```

If I do that with the original image, here are the images that result:

[image]

However, my original problem was that skimage's match_template only takes a 2D array. So, it turns out, I had the right arrays the whole time, I just didn't realize that they were right because displaying them results in the weird colors you see in the image in the question. If anyone knows why python does weird things when displaying a 2D image, I'd like to know. Otherwise, I've solved my problem. Thanks to anyone who attempted to help, whether you posted or just tried stuff on your own!

Edit - requested image rendering code:

```
def locate_squares(im):
    r,g,b = im.split()
    red = np.array(r)
    green = np.array(g)
    green_template = green[144:194,297:347]  #,144:194]
    gRadius = (green_template.shape[0]/2, green_template.shape[1]/2)
    red_template = red[145:195,252:302]    #,145:195]
    rRadius = (red_template.shape[0]/2, red_template.shape[1]/2)
    #print red_template

    plt.figure(1)
    plt.subplot(1,2,1)
    plt.imshow(green_template)
    plt.subplot(1,2,2)
    plt.imshow(red_template)

    plt.figure(2)
    plt.subplot(1,2,1)
    plt.imshow(green)
    plt.subplot(1,2,2)
    plt.imshow(red)

    plt.show()
```

Comment: It's not obvious from anything here what you're using to turn the ndarray into an image, but all of the ways of doing that which I can think of off my head expect a 3d array (width, height, planes). Maybe if you show the code you're using to render it would help.

Comment: Best guess: Let's say you're passing green_template to something that expects a 3d array. Since there is only one value at each (x,y), the renderer is trying to interpret this value as a 24- (or 32-)bit color. A binary representation of the color might elaborate the problem a bit better - instead of the 24-bit value '010001011001000101111111' (RGB triplet [127, 145,  69] as a single 24-bit number), you're passing '000000000000000010010011' (147 as a 24-bit number); ie., a pixel with LOTS of red, and zero green or blue. Hence, all pixels of green_template rendering as various shades of red.

Comment: I see. Yeah that makes sense. There was definitely a lot of red in both images.